# custom url scheme not working in Android react native

Tags: android, react-native, custom-scheme-url

Hello friends i want to integrate deep link in my react native project with custom url scheme so below is my code

```
render() {

return (
  <WebView
    ref="webViewAndroidSample"
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
    source={{uri:SITE_URL}}  
    style={{flex: 1}} />
  );
}

onNavigationStateChange (event) {

if(event.url === "myschemeapp://addHost?query=abc")
{
  alert('Success')
}
else{
  alert('Error')
}
```

}

Manifest File

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="myschemeapp" android:host="addHost" />

    </intent-filter>
```

**I face issue in Android device**
My main site url has two link inside main url and when i click first call onNavigationStateChange function but when i log it as event.url i always get my site main url not custom url **myschemeapp://addHost?query=abc** any idea how can i get solution for above issue  ? your all suggestions are appreciable.